# R DataTable Keep Columns After ColumnName

Tags: r, data.table

```
set.seed(1)
    data=data.frame("a"=sample(-5:5, 20, r=T),
    "b"=sample(-5:5, 20, r=T),
    "c"=sample(-5:5, 20, r=T),
"d"==sample(-5:5, 20, r=T))
library(data.table)
setDT(data)
```

I wish to create vector V that equal to all column names of 'data' that come after b.
so I wish for V=c("c","d") using datatable solution!

Comment: Building on the answer that Ronak Shah gave, if you just want to get the names of columns after "b" then something like this could help?
`colnames(data)[(match('b', names(data)) + 1):ncol(data)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be using `match` :

```
data[, (match('b', names(data)) + 1):ncol(data)]

#     c  d
# 1:  3  0
# 2:  2  1
# 3:  3  0
# 4:  1  2
# 5:  2  1
# 6:  0  5
# 7:  4 -5
#...
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `cumsum` to create a logical vector and subset the data columns

```
data[, .SD[, cumsum(cumsum(names(.SD)== 'b'))> 1, with = FALSE]]
#     c  d
# 1:  3  0
# 2:  2  1
# 3:  3  0
# 4:  1  2
# 5:  2  1
# 6:  0  5
# 7:  4 -5
# 8:  1 -2
# 9: -3  2
#10:  4  3
#11:  0  3
#12:  2  1
#13: -4 -2
#14: -4  1
#15:  0  0
#16:  0 -5
#17: -5 -1
#18: -3  0
#19: -3 -5
#20:  2  3
```